# How to configure springfox to use Gson instead of Jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to use Gson to send JsonObjects as response. These JsonObjects are constructed manually instead of using objectMapper or Gson. I excluded all the dependencies related to Jackson. It works well and good. Later I tried to add Swagger documentation using springfox. Now it throws below exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in springfox.documentation.spring.web.SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:235) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.honeywell.ldi.LdiDetailerApplication.main(LdiDetailerApplication.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [springfox(swagger2) does not work with GsonHttpMessageConverterConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219946/springfoxswagger2-does-not-work-with-gsonhttpmessageconverterconfig)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is due to `springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer`
complaining about missing `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

The `ObjectMapper` exists in `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar`. You would still need `jackson-databind` JAR to make your application work with Springfox.

As for SpringFox, it doesn't work with Gson out of the box. You need to register **custom serializers** for different Springfox artifacts with the `Gson` object.

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder()
    // needed for making calls to /v2/api-docs
    .registerTypeAdapter(Json.class, 
        new SpringfoxJsonSerializer())
    // rest are needed for making calls to /swagger-ui.html
    .registerTypeAdapter(ApiListing.class, 
        new SpringfoxApiListingJsonSerializer())
    .registerTypeAdapter(SwaggerResource.class, 
        new SpringfoxResourceJsonSerializer())
    .registerTypeAdapter(ResourceListing.class, 
        new SpringfoxResourceListingJsonSerializer())
    .registerTypeAdapter(UiConfiguration.class, 
        new SpringfoxUiConfigurationJsonSerializer())
    // needed if you have security
    .registerTypeAdapter(SecurityConfiguration.class, 
        new SpringfoxSecurityConfigurationJsonSerializer())
    ...
    .create();
```

**[Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/springfox-gson-example) is a working example with Spring Boot, SpringFox, and Gson.**

Comment: Thank you Indra Basak. This is helpful. I used SpringfoxJsonSerializer() and with this the /v2/api-docs works for me. However, the swagger-ui won't appear as expected and it keeps on saying fetching the resources. I noticed a strange thing that when I remove configureMessageConverters for GsonHttpMessageConverters, the API is available but won't work for custom constructed JsonOjects.  I appreciate your help in this.

Comment: You need the rest of JSON serializers to make your UI work. Please check the project I referred to.